# How can i return an html in a function in javascript as in jsx (react)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I want to create a function and have it return an html like in react (Without use react or jsx)

```js
const func = () => {
  return (
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without use react or jsx

If you don't want to use JSX then clearly you can't use JSX.  You can return a *string*:

```js
const func = () => {
  return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>';
}

document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = func();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Or perhaps an element:

```js
const func = () => {
  const el = document.createElement('h1');
  el.innerText = 'Hello World!';
  return el;
}

document.querySelector('#test').appendChild(func());
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: And without using quotes or createelement

Comment: @yepshushi: What do you mean?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: return an html in the function instead of a string

Comment: @yepshushi: And what do you consider to be "an html"?  If you want to use JSX without using React, [that may be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30430982/328193).  But in the question you *explicitly* state that you *don't* want to use JSX.  Now you're also stating that you don't want to use strings.  Or elements.  Do you even want to use JavaScript at all?  Are you even using a web browser?  What are these random restrictions and what problem are you actually trying to solve?  Please clarify the question instead of adding arbitrary requirements in comments.

Comment: sorry, what I'm trying to explain is that I wanted the component function to write as html ``return (<h1></h1>)``` and I was wondering if there was a way to do that without using jsx or babel, and I wanted it to return as a string when the function was executed, for example ```component() // => "<h1></h1>"```

Comment: @yepshushi: *"and I wanted it to return as a string when the function was executed"* - Then that would be the first example in this answer, using a string.  Again, if you don't want to use JSX then you can't use JSX.  Or maybe you're looking for [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)?  Or [template script elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4912586/328193)?

Comment: I'm currently using ```return "<h1></h1>"``` and I want it to look like this ```return (<h1></h1>)```

Comment: a bit confusing, i know

Comment: Why do you want it to look like that? That's not a string.

Comment: @yepshushi: You're just going in circles.  The question you're asking is, "How can I use JSX without using JSX?"  The answer is, "You can't.  For reasons which should be obvious."  There may be some other underlying problem you're trying to solve, but you're obscuring that problem with what you *think* is the approach to take, but you are mistaken.

Comment: right, that was my doubt, thanks